# how to access redux store from custom javascript

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to implement an external API library in a redux application.
I'm fresh new in redux so I don't know exactly how it works.

In my javascript using the API library, I wan't to access info from a container (the user firstanme if he's logged).

After reading some doc, I tried to import the store in my js file, to get the state of the user, but I can't reach the info I need.

Here's the code I tried :

```
import configureStore from '../store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();
const state = store.getState();
```

I get many info in state, but not the one I need. Any help ?

Comment: "I get many info in state, but not the one I need." be more specific. Are you sure "state of the user" is already there when you read current state?

Comment: when I make console.dir(state) I got many objects that are very specific to the application. I got one which is User, so I dive in it, but I could'nt find the firstname info.

Comment: Then I took a look at reducers/user and actions/user and I saw that the infos I get in the state seems to be define here, but as I am new in redux, I don't konw how to do to get the user firstname.

And as component like dashboard can reach this info to display it when the user is logged (with ${user.firstname} for example), I presume that I don't have to modify those file and it's just that I don't know how to get this info from an externel js file

Answer (score 1):

First of all it looks like `configureStore` creates new store every time you call it. But you need the very that `store` that your components will use and populate. So you need to somehow access the store you are passing your `Provider`.

Then since store state is "changing" you can't simply read it once. So your user data might be initially empty but available some time later.

In this case you could make it a Promise

```
const once = selector => available => new Promise(resolve => {
   store.subscribe(() => {
      const value = selector(value)
      if(available(value)) resolve(value)
   })
})
```

And usage

```
 const user = once(state => state.user)(user => user && user.fullName)

 user.then(user => console.log(`User name is ${user.fullName}`)
```

Or if your data might be changing more than once during application lifecycle you might want to wrap it with something that represent changing data (observable). [RX examle](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-rx/blob/master/src/observableFromStore.js)

Comment: configureStore() seems to return the store depending on conditions. It's used like this in index.js :

`const store = configureStore();
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    ...`

Comment: I try your code, but I didn't manage to display the console.log.

I try to add a reject in the promise to see if I got some error :
`const once = selector => available => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    store.subscribe(() => {
        const value = selector(value)
        if(available(value)) resolve(value)
        else reject("problem")
    })
});

const user = once(state => state.user)(user => user && user.firstname);

user
    .then(user => console.log(`User name is ${user.firstname}`))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
;`

but I got nothing...

Comment: @Poch It is almost impossible to say anything unless you provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demostrating the issue.

Comment: it's just that the code I test don't return anything. The console logs in user.then() & user.catch() don't return anything. just as if the code isn't executed :/

As it's a huge and complicated project and I just start react/redux, I think I'm gonna go read more basic documentation, and come back later...